# Allow anonymous access to vsts build artifacts in drop

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In VSTS after a successful build I can access to build drop location and download the build artifacts from here.

[image]

I can also get a url where I can download the files as a zip:

[image]

To access this url I need to authenticate. What would be the easiest way to give someone access to the build artifacts without having them to login?

Comment: From VSTS, publish the artifacts to a file share or file services (Dropbox and so on).

Answer (score 1):

For **Publish Build Artifacts task**, there are two types of locations you can publish the build artifacts.

[image]

- **Visual Studio Team Services/TFS:** only the users who have permissions to access to the build can get the build artifacts
- **A file share:** users who can access to the shared directory can get the build artifacts.

Besides, you can also hosted the build artifacts to the place where everyone can access (such as a public repo in GitHub). So you can add another task (such as PowerShell task) to commit and push the build artifacts to GitHub.